# Validate my approach for sharing "session" between Classic ASP and .NET webservices

Tags: .net, session, asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP system that's going to invoke various .NET webservices that produce reports. Clearly the session can't be shared between them, so instead of trying to shim a session module in SQL server, I thought instead about creating "tokens" for reports - i.e. a one-time use key that could be passed upon invocation from the ASP page via Ajax that would create the report and expire the key.

Are there any tricky things I should be aware of? Am I making this too simple? Or too complicated? They're all on the same IIS on Windows 2k3 Server

Comment: Why share session at all? Let the services be independent of the web application.

Comment: I have to authenticate the requester somehow.

Comment: That's not the main usage of Session state. Find a proper way to authenticate.

Comment: Session state is **widely** used for authentication. That said, I think the original premise of the token idea is a good one. Where were you planning on storing these tokens?

Comment: SQL Server database. Once a token is used it will be disabled, or if a tokenized process is invoked, it will check for expiry and then run the report and disable the token, or just disable the token.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a reasonable one.  Its pretty simple to implement (a GUID that is stored in a SQL table along with a timeout value).  I've used this approach myself in a number of places.